# UnhandledException when Binding Image URL in LongListSelector

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

```
            List<string> images = new List<string>();
            // add some image url to list
            DataContext = images;
```

I have a list of Image URL and i want to display it using LongListSelector

```
            <phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding}" LayoutMode="List">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

But after xaml page display completed, debug jump to method Application_UnhandledException in App.xaml.cs, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:
In xaml:

```
 <phone:LongListSelector Name="myLLS" LayoutMode="List" Height="300">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}" Height="60"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
 </phone:LongListSelector>
```

In code behind:

```
 ObservableCollection<Uri> myList = new ObservableCollection<Uri>();

  public MainPage()
  {
     InitializeComponent();

     myLLS.ItemsSource = myList;
     myList.Add(new Uri("Resources/Image1.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
     myList.Add(new Uri("Resources/Image2.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
  }
```

I've bound LLS itemssource to ObservableCollection of Uri's. It's working. ObservableCollection is also better here, as you can dynamically update your LLS - when you add or remove image. It's also good to fix the height of LLS, without that I sometimes got an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You don't bind to image URL, you should Bind to BitmapImage